# Is there a way to log this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out what "this" refers to.

Is there a way in js to console.log this?

```
console.log $(this).next
```

Comment: Can't you just do `console.log(this)`?

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean

```
console.log($(this).next());
```